# Can the Dual-Balanced weapon modification be applied to double weapons?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons

The [Dual-Balanced weapon mod description](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-modifications/dual-balanced/) says,

> Price +2,000 gp; Weight —
>
> Dual-balanced weapons are balanced to be wielded in tandem.
>
> Only melee weapons can be dual-balanced. When wielding two weapons with the dual-balanced modification, reduce any two-weapon fighting penalties by 1 for both weapons. The weapons do not need to be the same type, but both must have the dual-balanced modification.

Can I apply this mod to double weapons, such as a staff? I suspect there may be a problem with it RAW—if so, would it cause problems to allow it?

Comment: Please [avoid the term “RAI”](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7528/4563)—in the sense of “what *should* the rule be?” that is our default anyway, and in the sense of “what did the developers intend?” [we don’t handle those kinds of questions](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7964/4563). I have edited your question to, I think, get at what you’re really looking for while avoiding that term.

Comment: It's now unclear to me what you're asking. Are you asking, "Does the dual-balanced modification grant its benefits when applied to a double weapon?" Or are you asking, "It looks the dual-balanced modification doesn't work with double weapons, what would be the balance implications of a house rule that allowed it to do so?"

Comment: @ObliviousSage There is absolutely no reason why a single Question can’t handle both of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, weapon modifications do not address double weapons at all.

The available precedent—weapon special materials, magic weapon enhancement, and so on—treat the two ends of a double weapon as separate weapons.

> you can build a double weapon with each head made of a different special material.

<sup>([Equipment → Special Materials](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/special-materials/))</sup>

> Creating magic double-headed weapons is treated as creating two weapons when determining cost, time, and special abilities.

<sup>([Magic Item Creation → Creating Magic Weapons](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/Magic-Item-Creation/#Creating_Magic_Weapons))</sup>

Weapon modifications *should* work the same way—but we don’t have any explicit rule *saying that*.

Anyway, treating the two heads as separate weapons *can* cause a whole lot of confusion—[for example](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/79179/4563)—but in this case, extrapolating this rule to weapon modifications actually works out pretty much the way you’d like it to. Since the two heads are treated as two weapons when determining special abilities, they can each be made dual-balanced and then you’ll be “wielding two weapons with the dual-balanced modification.”

Ultimately, RAW, you can argue that weapon modifications apply to the whole double weapon as just one weapon, but being inconsistent with literally everything else makes that a very poor ruling to make in practice.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense; also, thanks for linking to the question on sunder, I had not thought about it until now.